# Vim: Changing appearance of line numbers (beyond standard options)

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying figure out how far I can go in fine-tuning the appearance of my Vim GUI. I'm using MacVim 7.3 and what I'd like to do is change the padding, text-alignment and border color of the line numbers.

I know there are some standard configuration parameters in the highlight command, particularly the gui group, but what if I want something beyond what's offered there? For example, a right border as opposed to underline. Is this possible?

It could be that it's simply not worth the trouble, but I'd like to at least know what the initial steps would be so I can make the call. (Even if it's just :help adding-border-to-line-numbers and I happened to miss it).

Thanks.

Comment: I realize this is probably a bad "answer", but I tend to think that displaying line numbers is overkill.  Use ###G to jump to the line you need, and save some screen real estate.

Comment: You might be right, but that's not what I'm asking. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you intend to go into vim's source and hack it from there, changing line numbers appearance beyond what highlighting offers is not possible.

However, I do remember a few patches that dealt with something of a kind, so you might want to check the archives. You will still need to recompile vim doing that (if you manage to find a patch that does that).

Comment: Do you know where this is handled in Vim's source? Or if it's Vim vs MacVim? Also, anything about the patches you remember is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @Thomas - Sorry, I never went through with it (when I was looking for that I wanded a way to change the font in which line numbers are displayed). I went through the patch archives on vim.org just now, but cannot seem to locate that one; if I stumble on it in the next few days I'll leave you a link.